# cURL using PHP: download file to client results in minorly corrupt file

Tags: php, curl

Using the script I will post below, I successfully download JPG, PNG or PPT(x) files from server to the client using cURL in PHP. However, when I open any of the powerpoint files I save in this manner I get an error "PowerPoint found a problem with content in FILENAME.pptx. Powerpoint can attempt to repair the presentation. If you trust the source of this presentation, click Repair."

```
function download_file( $linkRequested = '', $whichFileToDownload = '' )
{
    // literal dam reference. We dont want wider access to our files. 
    $fileWithPath = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/files/xxxXXX/specific/' . $whichFileToDownload;

    /***   define the file type for the download MT ***/
    // set generic mime type, in case we don't match 
    $mimeType = 'application/octet-stream';
    // JPG
    if ( preg_match('|\.jpg$|i', $whichFileToDownload) ) {
        $mimeType = 'IMAGETYPE_JPEG';
    }
    // PNG
    if ( preg_match('|\.png$|i', $whichFileToDownload) ) {
        $mimeType = 'IMAGETYPE_PNG';
    }
    // older PowerPoint 
    if ( preg_match('|\.ppt$|i', $whichFileToDownload) ) {
        $mimeType = 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint';
    }
    // PowerPoint 
    if ( preg_match('|\.pptx$|i', $whichFileToDownload) ) {
        $mimeType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation';
    }

    /***  do curl MT ***/
    $ch = curl_init($fileWithPath);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fileWithPath );

    $fp = fopen($fileWithPath, 'wb');

    // set the curl options. Order is important. 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

    // get the contents of the file as text 
    $content = curl_exec($ch);

    // describe the file header for the client 
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    // set mime type for download of binary data 
    header('Content-Type: ' . $mimeType);
    // Attachment indicates save the file. Filename sets file name
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $whichFileToDownload . '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($content));

    // send the file 
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    echo $content;

    // clean up loose ends 
    flush();
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);

    // don't return anything 
}
```

Am I not closing the stream correctly? I don't know what the problem is.

Notes: JPG and PNG files open fine. & Clicking on "repair" successfully opens the file.

Comment: I will say that in one instance, you have an error in your content-disposition, given that it expects `filename="'. $whichFileToDownload"'`, but you're missing the `""` encapsulation around the value. I can't find anything else though

Comment: It looks like you're trying to download a file from the same server as the script is running on... Use [`readfile($filename)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) to stream the file instead of loading it into a variable through cURL. Also, your regular expressions will match more than file extensions. They should be like `/\.jpg$/i` (literal period, only match at the end of the string)

Comment: compare the before/after versions of the files, e.g. load both into a hex editor, or a binary diff. you'll probably find some PHP errors/warnings or other "fluff" at the start or end of the file - probably the end.

Comment: I've included your bug fixes here and in my script. Now Im off to read up about readfile(). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acutally managing file download from the script isn't a good idea. Since your files are on your webserver it's better if you use a more robust approach such as: `x_sendfile` mod for apache:

https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/ <sup>ref</sup>

Usage:

```
    header("X-Sendfile: $path_to_somefile");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$somefile\"");
    exit;
```

Also, with your script you are giving away the possibility to pause and resume the download (you should manually manage `Range` and `Content-Range` header, and this is error-prone).

Comment: Interesting. I had never heard of that before. Here's a better explanation of what x_sendfile is / how it works for those interested: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/129/x-sendfile-serve-large-static-files-efficiently-from-web-applications/

Comment: (I am using IIS, so apache mods won't help.) But, I think I should have included some of my motivation. JPG and PNG files intended for download are forced to view by IE8+ because it is non-conforming to specification for the 'download' href attribute. So I built this tool to download for all browsers because filtering agents is less reliable. BUT I've realized just now that PPT isn't affected by the force-to-view functionality of IE8+, so I can just circumvent my problem by only using this script on images. Thanks, you may not have helped me directly, but this helped.